# Como puedo obtener el valor id de mi organismo correspondiente

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Espero explicarme bien y dar todos los datos neesarios.

En contexto, el sistema se trata de dependencias y de sus unidades administrativas correspondientes, entonces en la tabla Organismos de mi base de datos, quiero obtener el **id** de la unidad administrativa correspondiente para poder generarle un Corte

Tengo una View en la que imprime lo siguiente [image: vista de la imagen]

y este es el código de la View

```
@model IEnumerable<SER.Models.Organismo>

@{
    SER.Models.Organismo Dependencia = ViewBag.Dependencia as SER.Models.Organismo;
    ViewBag.Title = "Unidades Administrativas";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title de  @Dependencia.Nombre</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="active">
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
                </th>
                <th>Titular Actual</th>
                <th>Titular Entrante</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.TitularActualUA != null)
                        {
                            <p>@item.TitularActualUA.ObtenerNombreCompleto()</p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             @Html.Label("Se requiere un Titular", new { @class = "label label-danger" })
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.TitularEntranteUA != null)
                        {
                            <p>@item.TitularEntranteUA.ObtenerNombreCompleto()</p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (User.IsInRole("Administrador") || User.IsInRole("CoordinadorInterno")) 
                            { 
                                @Html.ActionLink("Agregar Titular Entrante", "Register", "Account", new { OrganismoId = item.Id, _Rol = "TitularEntrante" }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-primary" })
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Administrador") || User.IsInRole("CoordinadorInterno"))
                        {
                            if (item.TitularActualUA != null && item.TitularEntranteUA != null)
                            {
                                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="@Url.Action("passVerify", "cotejamiento")">Realizar Corte</a>




                                
                                //@Html.ActionLink("Realizar Corte", "PorUnidadAdministrativa", "Cortes", new { OrganismoId = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-info" })
                                

                            }
                        }
                        @Html.ActionLink("Ver cortes", "VerCortesPorUnidadAdministrativa", "Cortes", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-info" })

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

    </table>
```

El Model es el siguiente

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SER.Models
{
    [Table("Organismos")]
    public class Organismo
    {

        public Organismo() {
            this.FechaAlta = DateTime.Now;
            this.Activo = true;
            this.HabilitarPorPeriodo = false;
            this.OrdenProcesamiento = 5000;
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Padre")]
        public long? PadreId { get; set; }
        public virtual Organismo Padre { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Indique el tipo de organismo.")]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de organismo")]
        public long TipoOrganismoId { get; set; }
        public TipoOrganismo TipoOrganismo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(140)]
        public string Siglas { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Indique el nombre del organismo.")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/DD/YYYY}")]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de alta")]
        public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha de baja")]
        public DateTime? FechaBaja { get; set; }
       

        //Es para dar de baja
        public Boolean Activo { get; set; }

        //Es solo para desactivar
        [NotMapped]
        public Boolean Desactivar { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaDesactivada { get; set; }


        [StringLength(1000)]
        public String UsuarioDesactivada { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public Boolean SelectHabilitarPorPeriodo { get; set; }
        public Boolean HabilitarPorPeriodo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaApertura { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaCiere { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Orden (Número de ordenamiento)")]
        public int Orden { get; set; }

        public int? OrdenProcesamiento { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public long cantidadHijos { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public long cantidadHijosActivos { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public long cantidadHijosInactivos { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public long Nivel { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Proviene de Organismo")]
        public long? ProvieneOrganismoId { get; set; }
        //public virtual Organismo ProvieneOrganismo { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int PlantillasActivasAsignadas { get;set;}
        [NotMapped]
        public int PlantillasInactivasAsignadas { get; set; }

        private String _bc;

        [NotMapped]
        public String BreadCrumbOrganismo
        {
            get
            {
                return this._bc;
            }

            set
            {
                this._bc = ObtenerBreadCrumbOrganismo();
            }
        }

        public int CantidadPlantillasAsignadas(Boolean status = true) 
        {
            using (var db = new DAL.SERContext())
            {
                var cantidad = 0;
                try
                {
                    cantidad = db.PlantillaOrganismo.Where(m => m.OrganismoId == this.Id && m.Activo == status).GroupBy(m => m.PlantillaId).Count();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    cantidad = -1;
                    //Si tira un menos uno es un error.
                }
                return cantidad;
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Usuario TitularEntranteUA { get { return obtenerTitularEntranteUA(); } set { obtenerTitularEntranteUA(); } }
        private Usuario obtenerTitularEntranteUA()
        {

            var userOrganismo = new SER.DAL.SERContext().Usuarios.Where(m => m.OrganismoId == this.Id && m.Activo);
            var usersTitularEntrante = Roles.GetUsersInRole(new RolesSistema().TitularEntrante.Valor);
            foreach (var user in userOrganismo)
            {
                if (usersTitularEntrante.Contains(user.UserName))
                    return user;
               
            }
            return null;
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Usuario TitularActualUA { get { return obtenerTitularActualUA(); } set { obtenerTitularActualUA(); } }
        private Usuario obtenerTitularActualUA()
        {
            var userOrganismo = new SER.DAL.SERContext().Usuarios.Where(m => m.OrganismoId == this.Id && m.Activo);
            var usersTitular = Roles.GetUsersInRole(new RolesSistema().TitularUA.Valor);
            foreach (var user in userOrganismo)
            {
                if (usersTitular.Contains(user.UserName))
                    return user;

            }
            return null;
        }

        public List<Organismo> RutaOrganismo()
        {
            List<Organismo> ruta = new List<Organismo>();

            Models.Organismos.InformacionOrganismos iOrganismos = new Models.Organismos.InformacionOrganismos();
            ruta = iOrganismos.Ruta((long)this.Id);

            return ruta;
        }

        public String ObtenerBreadCrumbOrganismo()
        {
            List<Organismo> ruta = RutaOrganismo().ToList();
            List<String> nombresOrganismos = new List<String>();
            String strRuta = "";

            foreach (var r in ruta)
                nombresOrganismos.Add(r.Nombre);

            nombresOrganismos.Reverse();
            foreach (var nombre in nombresOrganismos)
                strRuta += nombre.Replace('-', ' ').Trim() + " > ";

            return strRuta.Trim().TrimEnd('>');
        }

        public Niveles ObtenerNivel() {

            Niveles nivel = Niveles.NA;

            try
            {
                using (var db = new SER.DAL.SERContext()) {
                    var padre = db.Organismos.FirstOrDefault(m => m.PadreId == null);
                    if (this.Id == padre.Id) {
                        nivel = Niveles.Gobierno;
                    }else if (this.PadreId != null && this.PadreId == padre.Id) {
                        nivel = Niveles.Dependencia;
                    }else if (this.PadreId != null && this.PadreId != padre.Id) {
                        nivel = Niveles.UnidadAdministrativa;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { 
            
            }

            return nivel;

        }

        public enum Niveles { Gobierno = 0, Dependencia = 1, UnidadAdministrativa = 2, NA = 10}

        public List<Cortes> Cortes { get; set; }

    }

    public class CalendarizarAccesoOrganismo {

        public List<Organismo> Dependencias { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaApertura { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Lo que yo quiero es que al momento de dar click en **realizar corte** me mandé a otra vista en la cual se va a verificar dos contraseñas, y al dar click en otro botón mandé a la vista donde se realizar el corte, el problema es que no sé realmente como hacerlo, aquí está la segunda vista

```
@model SER.Models.Verify

@using SER.Models;

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Verificar Contraseña";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SERLayout.cshtml";

   List<SER.Models.Organismo> organismos = new List<SER.Models.Organismo>();

}

<h2>Verificar contraseña</h2>

<h1>Ingresa los datos solicitados</h1>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserProfileTitular)</div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserProfileTitular, new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserProfileTitular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordTitular)</div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PasswordTitular, new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordTitular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserProfileEntrante)</div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserProfileEntrante, new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserProfileEntrante, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordEntrante)</div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PasswordEntrante, new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PasswordEntrante, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-5">

       @foreach (var item in organismos)
       {
           @Html.ActionLink("Fimar", "PorUnidadAdministrativa", "Cortes", new { OrganismoId = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
       }




       @{
           //@Html.ActionLink("Fimar", "PorUnidadAdministrativa", "Cortes", new { OrganismoId = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
       }


       <a class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("UnidadesAdministrativas", "Cortes")">Regresar</a>
   </div>
}
```

para poder acceder al corte me pide un parametro (igual que en la primera vista), pero no sé como pasarle el parametro correspondiente, porque ese **id** corresponde a esa unidad administrativa que está en la base de datos y no entiendo como en la primer vista funciona todo tal cual, obteniendo el **id** correspondiente y cuando trato de hacerlo igual, pero en la otra vista, no funciona.

El sistema no es mió, lo estoy adaptando y se me complica porque es mi primera vez usando c# y tambien asp.net mvc, sé que es muchísimo texto, pero es que no encuentro alguna manera para poder obtener ese **id** en especifico

este es el controlador de la primera vista

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CoordinadorInterno")]
public ActionResult PorUnidadAdministrativa(long OrganismoId)
{
    var sessionUser = this._sessionUser();

    if (!sessionUser.AuthorizeInOrganismo(OrganismoId))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { msg = "La Unidad Administrativa no le corresponde." });

    CorteUnidadAdministrativa corte = new CorteUnidadAdministrativa(this._sessionUser(), OrganismoId);
    return View(corte);
}


[Authorize(Roles = "CoordinadorInterno")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PorUnidadAdministrativa(long OrganismoId, String Nombre)
{
    CorteUnidadAdministrativa corte = new CorteUnidadAdministrativa(this._sessionUser(), OrganismoId);
    try
    {
        corte.Corte.Nombre = Nombre;
        if (corte.TitularEntranteUA == null || corte.TitularActualUA == null)
        {
            return Json(new { status = false, CorteId = corte.Corte.Id, estatus = corte.Corte.Estatus.ToString(), errores = corte.Corte.ResumenErrores.ToList(), exception = "No se cuenta con los Titulares." });
        }
        else
        {
            corte.Corte.TitularEntranteId = corte.TitularEntranteUA.Id;
            corte.Corte.TitularSalienteId = corte.TitularActualUA.Id;
            corte.RealizarCorte();
        }

        return Json(new { status = true, CorteId = corte.Corte.Id, estatus = corte.Corte.Estatus.ToString(), errores = corte.Corte.ResumenErrores.ToList() });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { status = false, CorteId = corte.Corte.Id, estatus = corte.Corte.Estatus.ToString(), errores = corte.Corte.ResumenErrores.ToList(), exception = e.Message.ToString() });
    }
}
```

Y este es de la vista 2

```
public ActionResult passVerify()
{
    return View(new Verify());
}

[Authorize(Roles = "TitularDependencia,TitularEntrante,TitularUA")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult passVerify(Verify verify)
{
    return View(verify);
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona?? Presionas el botón `Realizar Corte` y que pasa?

Comment: Al presionar el botón me manda a la segunda vista y ahí esta un formulario, entonces lo que quiero es que al terminar el formulario, vaya a esta vista " @Html.ActionLink("Ver cortes", "VerCortesPorUnidadAdministrativa", "Cortes", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-info" })" el problema es que me pide un parametro y no sé como obtenerlo, ya traté de hacerlo de la misma forma en la que se obtiene en esta primera vista, pero no me resulta. Espero haberme explicado :c

Comment: Lo mejor es que reorganices tu pregunta. Coloca sola la vista donde está ese botón y su respectivo controller

Comment: Si, entiendo, es que quería mostrar como estaba en la view que si funciona y como lo tenia en la segunda view, pero en esa segunda no funciona :c ahorita lo redacto mejor